# Number of partitions of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ whose blocks are arithmetic progressions of length $t$ or more

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

This question was inspired by the earlier question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157795/number-of-partitions-whose-blocks-form-arithmetic-progressions),where no lower bound on arithmetic progression size was given. In particular, $t\geq 3,$ is assumed here.

The set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ has $2^n$  subsets. It also has $B_n$ (the $n$th Bell number) partitions, where $B_n<2^{2^n}$ and $B_n<n^n$ for large $n$.

I would like to determine the number $A_{n,t}$ of partitions of 
$\{1,\ldots,n\}$ in which each block is an arithmetic progression and has size $\geq t\geq 3$. What can be said about the growth rate of $A_{n,t}$:

1. If $t$ is kept constant?
2. If $t=O(\log n),$ say?

If any other growing $t$ proves amenable to analysis, I would be interested in that case as well.

**Edit** In the light of the comments, there can be 3 scenarios, all interesting.

a) all with same difference.

b) all differences distinct.

c) differences all satisfy $t\leq d \leq D.$

Comment: I assume this will depend heavily on whether you assume all the progressions to share the same difference?

Comment: A question I raised in a paper a few years back is whether there is any $n$ for which there is a partition of $\{\,1,2,\dots,n\,\}$ into arithmetic progressions, each of length at least 3, and no two with the same common difference.

Comment: @Gerry, maybe you are interested in higher order Langford sequences? There is a solution with triplets for n=27 available on the internet.  Gerhard "Just A Short Search Away" Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Comment: Also, the nth Bell number is bounded by n!  ,  and I suspect your quantity can be bounded by a fractional power of the nth Bell number.  Gerhard "Chiming In With Tighter Bounds" Paseman, 2018.07.06.

Comment: @Gerhard, I see what you mean – http://dialectrix.com/langford.html explains higher order Langford sequences well. But the question I raised has an extra condition that I didn't mention. What I really want is a positive integer $n$, and a collection of congruences $x\equiv a_i\bmod{m_i}$, $m_i$ distinct, such that each number from $1$ to $n$ satisfies exactly one congruence, and each congruence is satisfied by at least $3$ of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.